How to add a new attribute to thousands of Mongodb documents in yii2 performant?
I have php + yii2 + mongodb running on linux in virtualbox (10 cores, 12 GB RAM). yii2-mongodb is installed. I have a csv file that contains 100.000+ records in 2 columns: custom identifier (not _id), and a number. I would like to add the number to the documents in the collection in mongodb where the custom identifier matches the document. I was trying several different approaches, like 1. $collection->update() in the while(fgetcsv) loop, 2. tried to create an array in while() like:
$command = $conn->createCommand();

while(fgetcsv...) {
    $command->addUpdate(['identifier' => $csvrow[0]], ['number' => $csvrow[1]]);
}

$command->executeBatch('collection');

it works but it is terribly slow. 10-20 records per second. I have tried to add a text index to the custom identifier in mongodb compass (I have 1(asc), -1(desc), 2dsphere and text), got no performance boost there. What am I missing?

Have a look at bulkWrite

Thanks, I have updated my post a little bit for more clarity. I guess executeBatch() is doing a bulkWrite in the background actually.

It should be much faster. Are you sure, you have an index defined on identifier?

i was adding a text type index to it, performance was the same.

Why a text type index? Maybe execute the Batch after 1000 or 10'000 lines.

Maybe for comparison try mongoimport. Would be like mongoimport ... --collection=collection --type=csv --headerline --mode=merge --upsertFields=identifier 

Why a text? I have 1(asc), -1(desc), 2dsphere and text - text looked the most uncomplicated :)

Why on earth 2dsphere? Simply {identifier: 1}

these are the available options in mongodb compass

okay, I have added a regular index in mongosh with createIndex({identifier:1}) like you suggested, and $collection->update() finished in seconds! Thank you, that was the reason. I bet executeBatch() is going to be even faster

@WernfriedDomscheit please post your indexing suggestion as a solution, so that I can accept as the answer.

Looks like you did not create an index or you created a wrong index. Use this one
db.collection.createIndexes([ { identifier: 1 } ], { unique: true })

By using bulkWrite it should get even faster. In order to avoid "out of memory" problems I would suggest
$ops = [];
while(fgetcsv...) {
    array_push($ops, [ 'updateOne' => [ [ 'identifier' => $csvrow[0] ], [ '$set' => [ 'number' => $csvrow[1] ] ] ] ]);
    if (count($ops)) > 10000 {
        $conn->createCommand()->addUpdate($ops)->executeBatch('collection');
        $ops = [];
    }
}
if (count($ops)) > 0 
   $conn->createCommand()->addUpdate($ops)->executeBatch('collection');


thanks, I have updated my original post with fixed executeBatch() example. It's faster, maybe twice as $collection->update() in the while(fgetcsv) loop.
